Possible to disable opening app when FCM notification is clicked in flutter?
I would like some notifications to just be information to the user but which don't open the app when clicked on. It looks like click_action is ignored by flutterfire now so I can't use this to tell the device not to open the app when user clicks on the notification.
Is there a way to do it?
